# Spacified columnized on-the-left line formatting to columnized data?

Tags: python, string, python-2.x

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxx1.11xxxxxxxxxx1.11xxxxxxxxxxx1.11
xxxxxxxxxxxxx1.11xxxxxxxxxx1.11xxxxxxxxxx11.11
```

1. Is there some ready module in Python with which I could easily do above like formatting 17signs, 14 signs and then 15 signs?
2. How can you get the thing n.b. the small difference with 1.11 and 11.11?

*N.b. the numbers could be larger but not greater than 10 signs. The linewise count 46 `(=17+14+15)` is constant.*

**[Update]** Notice that I am using Python 2.6.5 so getting error `ValueError: zero length field name in format` with suggestions.

Comment: This is trivial to fix: `'{0:x>17}{1:x>14}{2:x>15}'.format(11.1, 11.1, 11.1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a module or library to do this, use [string formatting](http://diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html). To avoid the `ValueError`, specify what index your parameter is in the supplied values:

```
"{0:>17}".format(11.1)
```

Comment: I'm assuming that padding the space with characters (`x` in this case) is good enough. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: see my edit (if you're in python 2.x you need to include an index offset in the format string, not sure about 3.x)

Answer (score 2):

String formatting is built-in:

- http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Examples for Python 2.7/3.1

```
>>> '{:x>17}'.format(s)
'xxxxxxxxxxxx11.11'

>>> '{:x>17}{:x>14}{:x>15}'.format(11.1, 11.1, 11.1)
'xxxxxxxxxxxxx11.1xxxxxxxxxx11.1xxxxxxxxxxx11.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone commented the right answer but removed it so I will post it here. I will remove it if s/he post it so the credits go to the right person.

```
('%17.2f%14.2f%15.2f' % (1.11, 1.11, 11.11))
```

Comment: This way doesn't let you pad with arbitrary characters (such as 'x').

Comment: For what it's worth, I removed it because @kelloti and @MYYN are right, it's cleaner to do `'{0:x>17}{1:x>14}{2:x>15}'.format(1.11, 1.11, 11.11)`.  (I haven't gotten around to really learning the new string formatting...) The only difference is that using `%17.2f`, etc, will always have 2 places to the right of the decimal point. (So `11.1` would be `11.10`, for example).